# IMAP Idle, possibility to miss events?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, imap

I'm implementing a mail listener in java, the listener enters IDLE until a new mail arrives, it prints the email subject and goes back into IDLE immediately again.

Is there a chance that I will miss events (new emails) between the two IDLEs that I'm issuing?

For example, I've tried sleeping for 10 seconds before going into IDLE again, and within these 10 seconds I sent 2 emails to the inbox I'm monitoring, and after the 10 seconds when I went back into IDLE my `MessageCountListener` only got called once, for the first email. The second was missed.

Maybe I shouldn't rely on `MessageCountListener`?

```
       messageCountListener = new MessageCountListener() {
            //lets go into idle again and then handle the message
            public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent ev) {
                Message message = ev.getMessages()[0];
                try {
                    SimpleLogger.info("New message, subject: " + message.getSubject());
                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //GeneralUtility.threadSleep(8000);

                startImapIdle();
            }
```

`startImapIdle()` is called initially and then gets re-called from `messagesAdded()` like above.

```
private void startImapIdle() {
    SimpleLogger.info("Idling now");

    Runnable r = () -> {
        try {
            inboxFolder.idle(false);
        } catch (FolderClosedException e) {
            SimpleLogger.warn("Push Error: [DISCONNECT]", e);
            GeneralUtility.threadSleep(mailListenerRetryInterval);
            startListening(inboxFolder);
        } catch (StoreClosedException e) {
            SimpleLogger.warn("Push Error: [GLOBAL DISCONNECT]", e);
            GeneralUtility.threadSleep(mailListenerRetryInterval);
            initConnection();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            SimpleLogger.warn("Push Error: [NO IDLE]", e);
            GeneralUtility.threadSleep(mailListenerRetryInterval);
            initConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            SimpleLogger.warn("Push Error: [UNKNOWN]", e);
            GeneralUtility.threadSleep(mailListenerRetryInterval);
            initConnection();
        }
    };

    imapIdleThread = new Thread(r);
    imapIdleThread.start();
}
```

edit: (new code)

```
   private void startImapIdle() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                SimpleLogger.info("Idling now");
                MailUtility.ensureFolderOpen(folder);
                folder.idle();
            } catch (FolderClosedException e) {
                SimpleLogger.warn("Push Error: [DISCONNECT]", e);
                GeneralUtility.threadSleep(mailListenerRetryInterval);
                startListening();
                break;
            } catch (StoreClosedException e) {
                SimpleLogger.warn("Push Error: [GLOBAL DISCONNECT]", e);
                GeneralUtility.threadSleep(mailListenerRetryInterval);
                initConnection();
                break;
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                SimpleLogger.warn("Push Error: [NO IDLE]", e);
                GeneralUtility.threadSleep(mailListenerRetryInterval);
                initConnection();
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                SimpleLogger.warn("Push Error: [UNKNOWN]", e);
                GeneralUtility.threadSleep(mailListenerRetryInterval);
                initConnection();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you doing this? The below code works pretty well.

> inbox.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountAdapter() { ... })

Of course you need to have another infinite loop something like:

> ```
>           while (true) {
>                   IMAPFolder f = (IMAPFolder)inbox;
>                   f.idle();
>           }
> ```

Comment: Added some code above. I don't understand why would you .idle() inside an infinite loop. The specs says: The client MUST NOT send a
   command while the server is waiting for the DONE, since the server
   will not be able to distinguish a command from a continuation.

Comment: The api doc (https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#idle-- ) says idle will return if another thread issues a command on that folder. It also advices to use this in a loop. Please look at the monitor.java from the sample code (http://java.net/projects/javamail/downloads/download/javamail-samples.zip)

Comment: Thanks for the references. I changed the way that I'm doing this and I put the idle inside an infinite loop, now I think I'm not missing any events. Honestly though I still don't understand why my original approach missed some events even though I was issuing .idle() as soon as it's interrupted. You can check original post for code changes. Anyway things are working for now so I'll accept this, thank you.